# How to search for reserved characters in lucene?

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I want to search for  `@2` word. My pattern is `KEY("\\@2")`. My query veriable are;

```
if(querys==null) {
    querys = new ArrayList<Query>();
    querys.add(new RegexpQuery(new Term("content",RegexPattern.KEY.getPattern())));
}
```

and searching is

```
if(topDocs==null) {
    topDocs = new ArrayList<TopDocs>();
    for(int i =0;i<querys.size();i++) {
        topDocs.add(searcher.search(querys.get(i),100000));
    }
}
```

For example;

`KEY("Alex")`  and I am indexing my data which is have "Alex" word and I got 1 score.

If `KEY("@x")` I got 1 score too because '@' mean any string.

But I need to search for reserved characters which is @, for mail regex. How can I fix this?

If I try directly `KEY("@2")` is will find like; 
any string + ending 2

Lucene says If you want to use reserved characters like @ you need to use \ characters like \@2 but when I try the score is 0.

Comment: I am refferring [lucene docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html)

Comment: What you want to match? which words, can you show us some expected matches words

Comment: I want to match directly '@2' in indexed text.